# Custom mask for phone numbers

Tags: javascript, masking

I am using the jsmask plugin to mask telephone numbers.
The requirements are

1. It can have optional + at the start
2. It can have spaces in between

I tried this 
    `$('#Telephone').mask('+0000000 000 000 0000', { reverse: true });`
but it aint accepting optional plus.
Is there an inbuilt format or can we have a custom format for it 
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible.

You can add optional parameters only in end of the input.

They have an open pull request in Github.

You can check it [here](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/issues/354).

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working, you can try it.I have created [solution in JSfidller](https://jsfiddle.net/raihanuahmed/wjkfjr76/4/) for you. check it if you want.
**HTML:**

```
<form id="example-form" name="my-form">
    <label>Phone number:</label><br />
    <input id="phone-number" name="phone-number" type="text" maxlength="21" placeholder="+XXXXXXX XXX XXX XXXX" /><br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Script:**

```
    $('#phone-number', '#example-form')

        .keydown(function (e) {
            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
            $phone = $(this);

            // Adding blankspace in 9th, 13th and 17th position. 
//Change it according to your need
            if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
                if ($phone.val().length === 8) {
                    $phone.val($phone.val() + ' ');
                }
                if ($phone.val().length === 12) {
                    $phone.val($phone.val() + ' ');
                }           
                if ($phone.val().length === 16) {
                    $phone.val($phone.val() + ' ');
                }
            }

            // Allow numeric number and tab, backspace, delete keys only.
//Change it according to your need
            return (key == 8 || 
                    key == 9 ||
                    key == 46 ||
                    (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                    (key >= 96 && key <= 105)); 
        })

        .bind('focus click', function () {
            $phone = $(this);

            if ($phone.val().length === 0) {
                $phone.val('+'); // as your phone number start with '+'
            }
            else {
                var val = $phone.val();
                $phone.val('').val(val); // Ensure cursor remains at the end
            }
        })

        .blur(function () {
            $phone = $(this);

            if ($phone.val() === '+') {
                $phone.val(''); // if somebody type '+' it will be vanish 
            }
        });
```